# What is the difference between the regression and linear regression tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-disambiguation

## Quick Summary

I was looking at some of my badge progress tags and noticed two peculiar tags. One is [regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regression) and the other is [linear-regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-regression). I didn't find anything immediately on their difference on the Meta, so I tried taking a look at their descriptions. For [regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regression), I found this:

[image]

Sounds reasonable enough. Yet here is the description for [linear-regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-regression):

[image]

## Necessary?

[image]

Both seem fairly generic yet also seem to be handling the same thing. Looking at the [burnination guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191), I saw these metrics for tags:

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** I would say linear-regression is fairly generic despite its counterpart being the better catch-all for questions (see below).
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** Yes I would say so for both.
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** One does but certainly not both.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** I think this is another place where I would ding [linear-regression]. There are also non-linear regressions and the other tag seems to be a much better catch all in that respect.

Is there a reason there are two separate tags? I wasn't sure if this qualified for burnination, but I've tagged this question for it in case its relevant. I apologize if this question has already been beaten to a pulp here and feel free to delete it if you think it's just more mindless banter on tags. I think my main beef for selfish reasons was having my score divided up by tags that accomplish basically the same thing.

## Edit

Based on the comments this seems more a disambiguation problem than a burnination problem. I have retagged the question accordingly.

Comment: "Regression" has an important secondary meaning; I would wager that a substantial number of questions with this tag are about test regressions, not mathematical ones, in spite of the tag description. (A quick scroll through the questions with [tag:regression] and "test" reveals fewer than I thought, but on the order of 5-10%)

Comment: Tags having the same meaning are more of a case for [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) rather than burnination. In this case [tag disambiguation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-disambiguation/info) might be more appropriate given tripleee's comment

Comment: Proposed disambiguation: `regression` questions that are about regression tests can be retagged `regression-testing`; others can be retagged `regression-analysis`, and `linear-regression` would also be a synonym for `regression-analysis`.

Comment: (There are 220 questions in the [`regression-testing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regression-testing) tag. Many seem to be mistagged, e.g., questions that don't seem to have anything to do with regression testing (tags fillers).)

Comment: Mathematically, [not all regression analysis is linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression) (see e.g. [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression)), but as Stack Overflow is a programming site rather than a maths/stats site, this distinction probably doesn't matter enough to have `linear-regression` as a separate tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Regression" refers to two totally different ideas in programming: a generalization of linear regression (i.e. a mathematical technique), and a failure in a *regression test* (i.e., code that worked before, stopped working). So that tag is ambiguous as is. Per the comments, there are a significant fraction of questions trying to use the tag in the latter way.

Meanwhile, I don't see a particularly good reason to single out linear regression vs. other forms.

So: let's retag questions with `regression-analysis` when they're about the math (we can let `linear-regression` be a synonym), and use `regression-testing` for the questions about testing.